# How to create an Installer and search the programm in Windows Search bar?

Tags: visual-studio, registration, visual-studio-installer

I developed a Windows Forms Application in Visual Studio. After finishing it, i created an installer with the "Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects 2022". The project contains multiple single projects. Background is, that one is for logging in and start different modules. All modules/projects are setup as "primary output".
The installer works as expected, apart from one aspect. I can't search the pogram in the windows search bar. To be clear, i only want to search for the login. But all i can find is the installer itself...

I tried to change the registration. Default value was `vsdrpDoNotRegister`. But with `vsdrpCOM` i get the same result as well as with `vsdrpCOMRelativePath`. Furthermore I tried to change the target platform but withou any success. Can anyone help?

Comment: Definitely not the registration setting.  *Probably* the login project's Project > Properties > Application > Assembly Information settings.  For .NET5+ enter them through Project > Properties > Package.

Comment: @HansPassant the assembly information seems to be right. The checkbox for "make assembly com visible" is chekced.
I'm using .NET Framework 3.5 and 4, but not .NET 5 or higher...